# Callback for DidReceiveData in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a GET service call for which I must perform certain actions when a response is received.

The delegate methods, blocks actually, in `AFNetworking`, to my knowledge, only notify when a request is completed or failed wholly.

With a little in-depth look at `AFNetworking`, I discovered that `AFURLConnectionOperation` gets the callbacks

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

Now, my question is, how can I get this callback in the class which initiated the request?

P.S. I tired sending an `NSNotification` using `NSNotificationCenter` and I did get notified. However, due to multiple simultaneous requests being sent to server, I was unable to distinguish which request's response was I being notified of.

**EDIT**

I noticed that `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is inherited from `AFURLConnectionOpertaion` so I could possibly implement `connection:didReceiveData` method of `NSURLConnectionDelegate` but problem again is, how do I send a callback from there. :(

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ -> "How do I track upload or download progress?"

Comment: Hmmm .... I am using an implementation of `AFHttpClient` for my Application. How would I set those progress blocks?

Comment: Something like this: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/your_path.php" parameters:nil];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:blah failure:blah];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead){
    myProgressView.progress = (float)totalRead/totalExpected;
};

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

Comment: see also this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/96

Comment: ok, gonna try that ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example, which works:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[HTTPClient sharedInstance] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:iurl parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[HTTPClient sharedInstance] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failure");
    }];
    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^( NSUInteger bytesRead , long long totalBytesRead , long long totalBytesExpectedToRead )
     {
         NSLog(@"%lld of %lld", totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
     }
     ];
    [[HTTPClient sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```